# Part specification error when reading a column

Tags: list-manipulation, warning-messages, filtering

I have a `ReadList` of just some real numbers, called data. I'm trying to extract the data of specific columns from my list. When I execute the following

```
data[[All,1]]
```

I get this error:

> Part::partd: Part specification {-11.7056,-1.82099,8.23499,18.509,28.6437,-6.42392,2.4783,11.4386,-11.117,<<34>>,-7.02967,-8.13113,437.567,446.853,456.65,467.2,476.809,<<951>>}[[All,1]] is longer than depth of object.

However, whenever I type `data[[All,0]]` , the output is just the word `"Real"` over and over again. I assume it's telling me whether each value in the list is real or nonreal. I expected that this would either actually read me a column from my list or just give me the same error as before. Why is this different?

Can anyone tell what's going on? Is there a different way to extract a column of data from this list? Is it possible the list isn't actually ordered into columns at all?

Answer (score 3):

`data[[All,1]]` refers to the first element of all elements from `data`. Since elements of data aren't lists, they have no first elements at all. `[[All,0]]` refers to the type of data, which is a real number and not a list.

Your data is a list of real numbers, and not 2D array.
You can check that by `Dimensions[data]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using`ReadList` reads each line in a file and returns a list of them. This can sometimes lead to an array of data which is not a matrix. In such cases `data[[All,i]]`, where `i` is a secondary dimension index at which we could expect to have a value, could yield an error that you are writing about. In such cases even using a `Dimensions[data]` will not help, because it will just tell you number of the rows.

I am talking about this: 
`NotAMatrix = {{-1, -2, -8}, {-5, -45}};
TableForm[%]
Dimensions[NoMatrix]
NoMatrix[[All, 3]]`